# Restrict x domain to several regions

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot a graph and show only the low x-positions and the high x-positions. Right now I use two times `\addplot` with `restrict x domain` to achieve this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}  

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xmin=-3, xmax=5]

\addplot[restrict x to domain=-3:-1] 
coordinates {
(-3, 8.31160034e-02)
(-2, 2.54685628e-02)
(-1, 7.40715288e-03)
(0, 2.10192154e-03)
(1, 5.87352989e-04)
(2, 1.62269942e-04)
(3, 3.40715288e-03)
(4, 7.40715288e-03)
(5, 2.40715288e-02)
};

\addplot[restrict x to domain=1:5] 
coordinates {
(-3, 8.31160034e-02)
(-2, 2.54685628e-02)
(-1, 7.40715288e-03)
(0, 2.10192154e-03)
(1, 5.87352989e-04)
(2, 1.62269942e-04)
(3, 3.40715288e-03)
(4, 7.40715288e-03)
(5, 2.40715288e-02)
}; 

\end{axis}    

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I wonder if the trick can also be done with just one `\addplot`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
restrict expr to domain={<expr>}{min:max}
```

with in this case `<expr>` any appropriate function of `x`.  In your particular example, using `{x*x}{1:+inf}` would work because of the particular choice of ranges which happen to have `+/-1` as their end-points.  In general one could use

```
restrict expr to domain={(x>=a1)*(x<=b1)+(x>=a2)*(x<=b2)}{1:+inf}
```

to restrict to `x` to lie in one of the two intervals `a1:b1` and `a2:b2`, since `(x>=a)` returns `1` when true and `0` otherwise.  This type of expression is also better from the point of view of overflow in calculations.  Alternatively you can use `&&` for "and" and `||` for "or" operations:

```
restrict expr to domain={(x>=-3)&&(x<=-1)||(x>=1)&&(x<=5)}{1:1}
```

noting that `&&` has higher precedence.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}  

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-3, xmax=5]
\addplot[restrict expr to domain={x*x}{1:+inf}] 
coordinates {
(-3, 8.31160034e-02)
(-2, 2.54685628e-02)
(-1, 7.40715288e-03)
(0, 2.10192154e-03)
(1, 5.87352989e-04)
(2, 1.62269942e-04)
(3, 3.40715288e-03)
(4, 7.40715288e-03)
(5, 2.40715288e-02)
};
\end{axis}    
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-3, xmax=5]
\addplot[restrict expr to domain={(x>=-3)*(x<=-1)+(x>=1)*(x<=5)}{1:+inf}] 
coordinates {
(-3, 8.31160034e-02)
(-2, 2.54685628e-02)
(-1, 7.40715288e-03)
(0, 2.10192154e-03)
(1, 5.87352989e-04)
(2, 1.62269942e-04)
(3, 3.40715288e-03)
(4, 7.40715288e-03)
(5, 2.40715288e-02)
};
\end{axis}    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! I didn't think in this direction. Just for my understanding: in the expression 
`restrict expr to domain={(x>=a1)*(x<=b1)+(x>=a2)*(x<=b2)}{1:+inf}` wouldn't it be enough to restrict the range to `{1:1}` (for a1<b1<a2<b2)?

Comment: Yes, in the case of non-overlapping intervals the range `{1:1}` would be good enough.  However, you decided to change one endpoint and overlapping then occurred you might get surprised.